# Staying more than ninety days in Andorra, San Marino, Monaco, Vatican, …

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, micro-states

It’s possible (not always convenient) to enter Monaco from the Mediterranean, but getting into Andorra, San Marino, or Vatican City requires going through a Schengen country.  Is it possible (and legal) to skirt the Schengen 90/180 rule by proving (for example) that thirty of your one hundred days were spent within one or more of the micro-states?  How much/what kind of proof would be needed?  Seems an entry/exit stamp would not be persuasive, since I could ask for a stamp, enter, and then promptly leave without a stamp.

Comment: Andorra says citizens of some countries can stay 183 days.  But they also allegedly won't admit anyone who can't legally be in France or Spain.  (How can they keep that promise without border checks?)

Comment: If both France and Spain are in the same Customs area, and Andorra doesn't have any airports or seaports, then how would someone "land" in Andorra? Chord tunnel?

Comment: No one said anything about landing in Andorra.  Rather, “getting into Andorra, … requires going through a Schengen country.”

Answer (score 0):

For Andorra: if you have the corresponding stamps in your passport, the days there could be considered outside the Schengen Area.

For Monaco: You will receive a French Schengen entry/exit stamps when coming in or travelling out through Monaco.

San Marino and the Vatican have open borders agreements, so days there will count as inside the Schengen Area.

In the end, the Schengen enter/exit stamps are what counts.

The Border control can, however, accept alternative proof should a stamp be missing. They, however, have the last say as to whether the proof is considered sufficient.

---

**Sources**:

- [Andorra–European Union relations - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andorra%E2%80%93European_Union_relations#Border_controls)
- [Visa policy of Monaco - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Monaco)

  - [Visiting Monaco / Information and Services / Embassy of Monaco in France - Monaco embassy in France](https://ambassade-en-france.gouv.mc/en/Information-and-Services/Visiting-Monaco)
- [San Marino–European Union relations - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marino%E2%80%93European_Union_relations)
- [Visa policy of Vatican City - Wikipedia](https://enwikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Vatican_City)